# How to use StandardTokenizer from lucene 5.x.x

Tags: java, lucene, tokenize

There are a lot of examples that show how to use the StandardTokenizer like this:

```
TokenStream tokenStream = new StandardTokenizer(
            Version.LUCENE_36, new StringReader(input));
```

But in newer Lucene versions this constructor is unavailable. The new constructor looks like this:

```
StandardTokenizer(AttributeFactory factory)
```

What is the role of this AttributeFactory and how can i tokenize a String in newer versions of Lucene?

Comment: Have you tried passing the singleton `AttributeFactory.DEFAULT_ATTRIBUTE_FACTORY`? Or use the parameter-less constructor?

Comment: Hi Simon thanks for the tips. It does work with this code:
Tokenizer tokenStream = new StandardTokenizer();
tokenStream.setReader(new StringReader(input));

You then get an TokenStream when you apply your filter.

The TokenStream workflow has also changed, you now need to call reset(); Before you start consuming from this stream.

Comment: Is this question answered then?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `AttributeFactory` creates `AttributeImpl`s which are sources for `Attribute`s.  Attributes govern the behavior of the `TokenStream`, which is the underlying mechanism used for reading/tracking the data stream for the `StandardTokenizer`.

Little has changed from 4.x to 5.x with respect to the `AttributeFactory` - in both versions, you can create a `StandardTokenizer` with an `AttributeFactory` if you'd like, or if you don't specify one, then `AttributeFactory.DEFAULT_ATTRIBUTE_FACTORY` will ultimately end up being used.

The big difference was that you could also pass in a `Reader` for the input stream as part of the constructor.  This means that in 4.x, you would have to create a new StreamTokenizer for each input stream you wanted to process, which would in turn have to re-initialize attributes from the `AttributeFactory`.

I'm no Lucene dev, but my guess is that this is just a restructure to encourage reuse of the attributes across the reading of multiple streams.  If you take a look at the internals of the [TokenStream](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.lucene/lucene-core/5.0.0/org/apache/lucene/analysis/TokenStream.java#TokenStream) and the default [AttributesFactory](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.lucene/lucene-core/4.9.0/org/apache/lucene/util/AttributeFactory.java#AttributeFactory.StaticImplementationAttributeFactory) implementation, there is a LOT of reflection involved with creating and setting attributes.  If I had to guess, the `StreamTokenizer` constructor that takes a reader was just removed to encourage reuse of the tokenizer and its attributes because initialization of those attributes is relatively expensive.

EDIT

Adding a long-overdue example - sorry for not leading with this:

```java
// Define your attribute factory (or use the default) - same between 4.x and 5.x
AttributeFactory factory = AttributeFactory.DEFAULT_ATTRIBUTE_FACTORY;

// Create the tokenizer and prepare it for reading
//  Lucene 4.x
StandardTokenizer tokenizer = 
        new StandardTokenizer(factory, new StringReader("Tokenize me!"));
tokenizer.reset();
//  Lucene 5.x
StandardTokenizer tokenizer = new StandardTokenizer(factory);
tokenizer.setReader(new StringReader("Tokenizer me!"));
tokenizer.reset();

// Then process tokens - same between 4.x and 5.x
// NOTE: Here I'm adding a single expected attribute to handle string tokens,
//  but you would probably want to do something more meaningful/elegant
CharTermAttribute attr = tokenizer.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
while(tokenizer.incrementToken()) {
    // Grab the term
    String term = attr.toString();

    // Do something crazy...
}
```

Comment: I'd like to offer my bounty to @RustyBuckets, how do I to that?

Comment: @Filip i guess its already too late, sry i only saw the answer today. RustyBuckets thanks for the explanation, maybe you can also add a simple code example on how to use the new StandardTokenizer i think it might help some people. I currently use it like that:
Tokenizer source = new StandardTokenizer();
source.setReader(new StringReader(mytext));

Comment: Yes plz, a snippet of code as an example would be really helpful